# jQuery data-id undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unsure why I am not getting my `data-id` value its being showed as `undefined`

The `data-id` shows an int

```
<li>
    <input style="width:100%;" placeholder="Page Title" id="post_title" onclick="urlCheck()" dataid="<?php echo($website_id);?>" name="post_title" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('post_title', $post['post_title']); ?>" />
    <?php echo form_error('post_title'); ?>
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
function urlCheck() {

    $(".postForm").on('click', '#post_title', function (e) {
        var id = $('#post_title').attr("data-id");

        console.log(id);

        e.preventDefault();

    });
}
```

Comment: There is no hyphen `-` in your html.Try `.attr("dataid")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `dataid` instead of `data-id`, and to retrieve the attibute you need  to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()`

change this:

```
<input style="width:100%;" placeholder="Page Title" id="post_title" onclick="urlCheck()" dataid="<?php echo($website_id);?>" name="post_title" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('post_title', $post['post_title']); ?>" />
```

to this:

```
<input style="width:100%;" placeholder="Page Title" id="post_title" onclick="urlCheck()" data-id="<?php echo($website_id);?>" name="post_title" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('post_title', $post['post_title']); ?>" />
```

and retrieve the data in this mode:

```
var id = $('#post_title').data("id");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your attribute is `dataid`, not `data-id`.